# How delete obj with condition in view

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My model

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Phone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Osoba, editable=False, related_name='phone', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Osoba, editable=False, related_name='email', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I would like to be possible to delete an object only if there is no value in his fields

```
def delete_user(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)

    if not user.email or user.phone:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user.delete()
            print(user.email)
            return redirect('list_users')


    return render(request,'index-delete.html', {'user': user})
```

I tried this but it doesnt work

Comment: Doesn't work how? What happens?

Comment: What is not working with it?

Comment: you need to change related_names to avoid confusion. Since you have one-to-many relationships, you should use `related_name="emails"` and `related_name="phones"` so it's clear the query can return multiple objects. Also you need to test whether they exist using querying: `user.emails.exists()` and `user.phones.exists()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition is `not user.email.exists() and not user.phone`, since the `not` has precedence over the `and` and `or`:

```
def delete_user(request, id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not user.email.exists() and not user.phone.exists():
            user.delete()
            return redirect('list_users')
    return render(request,'index-delete.html', {'user': user})
```

So here the `user` will be removed if *both* the `email` and `phone` are blank (have truthiness `False`).

We can make it more efficient by searching in the database:

```
def delete_user(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        done, __ = user.objects.filter(id=id, email=None, phone=None).delete()
        if done:
            return redirect('list_users')
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'index-delete.html', {'user': user})
```

Here we thus perform the JOINs on the database, to know with one query if the user has no email and phone.

Comment: When i enter this condition and creating POST then nothing happend

Comment: Are you sure you (a) make a POST request, and (b) the user has an empty/null email *and* phone?

Comment: When i delete ``` if not user.email and not user.phone ``` everything works. I printed this values and they are  ```phonebookapp.Email.None```

Comment: @Curendos: hold on, that means `email` is a one-to-many relation?